# Stability of "separating set" under continuous maps that preserve boundaries

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

Let $B$ be the unit closed ball in $\mathbb{R}^d$ and $f:B\to B$ a continuous map such that $f(\partial B)=\partial B$, where $\partial B$ is the boundary of the ball (i.e. the sphere).
If $K\subset B$ is a set such that $B\setminus K$ is disconnected, do we have that $B\setminus f(K)$ is disconnected?

More generally, I am interested about the stability of the notion of "separating set" under the action of a continuous map from a domain to itself that preserves boundaries. I'd be glad if you had ideas, or pointers, even under slightly different or stronger assumptions (such as $f$ is homotopic to the identity).

Answer (score 1):

I'll consider the case $d=2$ and the square $D=\{(x,y),-1\le x,y\le 2\}$ instead of the ball.

Consider the map $f$ defined by $f(x,y)=(x,y)$, when $-1\le y\le 0$, $f(x,y)=(x,2y)$, when $0\le y\le 1$ and $f(x,y)=(x,2)$, when $1\le y\le 2$.

It is easy to check that $f(\partial D)=\partial D$, but the set $K=\{(x,y)\in D,0\le y\le 1\}$ separates $D$, while $f(K)$ does not.

Comment: Thank you! That's  indeed, one possible behavior. I have to reformulate my question to avoid this case.

Comment: @Chila I think to avoid anything like this you'll have to ask for $f$ to be an injection, which means homeomorphism, which is not interesting...

Comment: Yes the injection property is too strong. Given your answer, I can reformulate: the fact which I am curious about is, if 2 points $(a,b)$ are in distinct connexe components of $B\setminus K$ *and* $f(a),f(b) \notin f(K)$, then $(a,b)$ are in distinct connexe components of $B\setminus f(K)$.

Comment: @Chila For the square $0\le x,y\le 4$:  $f(x,y)=(x,2y)$ for $y\in[0,2]$, $f(x,y)=(x,6-y)$ for $y\in[2,3]$ and $f(x,y)=(x,y)$ for $y\in[3,4]$. Take $K$ to be the horizontal middle line.

Comment: Thank you, your counter-examples improved my understanding of the question. Actually I should have rather asked: under which hypothesis is such kind of property true?